# Organizing bookmarks in Safari for Windows

Tags: safari, windows, bookmarks

(Please tell me which site to post this on if this is the wrong one.)

My internet safety software is failing spectacularly with Chrome at the moment, and I have to uninstall it.  So I thought I'd try Safari, since that is supposedly compatible with the safety software.

I installed Safari 5.34.57.2 downloaded from File Hippo.  I exported my bookmarks from Chrome and imported them to Safari.  I would like the layout of bookmarks and bookmark folders to look approximately like it did in Chrome.

Chrome bookmarks bar:

[image]

---

Safari for Windows bookmarks bar:

[image]

---

I would like to get my bookmarks up there next to "Google Maps".  Ideally I would like a simple method involving highlighting and dragging *groups* of items, so I don't have to move things one at a time.  However, I would be reasonably happy if I could drag things individually.  Right now, I can't even do that.

I would also like to get rid of the awful black rectangle shown when I view all the bookmarks.  I was able to resize it slightly but it still takes up a lot of space.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into preferences, you should be able to tell safari which bookmarks folder to use for the **Favorites Bar**.
I don't have a PC, but on Mac this setting is under General in Safari.
After going to each website, the black boxes should go away, and be replaced by screenshots of the website.

1. Go into Safari Settings.
2. There is an item called Favorites Bar.
3. You should be able to change the Fav Bar folder to the on you imported from Chrome.

Comment: *I wouldn't recommend downloading software from 3rd parties* -- but Apple doesn't offer a download for Windows.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm sorry, I didn't realize that.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you give me something more step by step, please?  It's okay if it's the sequence of steps you would do in your set-up -- I'll try to adapt it.